# how to read the image captured using camera in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have done number plate extraction for static image i.e. image stored in the matlab working folder. Now wish to check the program functionality for real time, it means, i want to capture the car image using camera and feed this as input to matlab program. How can i do it?Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For this its worth checking out the [Image Acquisition Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq.html) toolbox which is designed for use with a camera feed that you described.

One way of doing this would then be to use the [getsnapshot](https://de.mathworks.com/help/imaq/getsnapshot.html) function to return a single image frame from the video feed.

Using this way, you could keep your current code you developed to work on a static image in your directory (provided its quick enough to work at the sample rate you are calling `getsnapshot`).

i.e. something like

```
numberOfFramesCaptured = 0; % Initialize frame counter

obj = videoinput('matrox', 1); % Create hardware input from camera

% Run loop until 100 frames have been captured
while(numberOfFramesCaptured < 100)
    frame = getsnapshot(obj); % Get a single frame
    checkNumberPlateImage(frame); % Call your image processing function
    numberOfFramesCaptured = numberOfFramesCaptured + 1; % Increment frame counter
    pause(x); % Change the delay between each frame that is captured by x seconds
end
```

Comment: I run the code and got the error :There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO. I run info = imaqhwinfo('matrox') in command window and got the answer as AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2014a\matrox\adaptor\win64\mwmatroximaq.dll'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.7 (R2014a)'
          AdaptorName: 'matrox'
            DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
           DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct] why device ids are zero?

Comment: From the looks of it it cant find that specific hardware; its worth running through the [official guide](https://de.mathworks.com/help/imaq/basic-image-acquisition-procedure.html#f9-69058) to getting started with the image acquisition toolbox setup. Particularly the part where it says _To determine the name of the adaptor, enter the imaqhwinfo function at the MATLAB prompt without any arguments._ This will give you a list of the adaptors available. You can then use `info = imaqhwinfo('adapterName')` to return a correct device ID.